# Does every interrupt need its own function?

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I am currently planning a project which includes multiple rotary encoders which I want to wire to interrupt pins to reliably get inputs from them.
I want every encoder to do essentially the same thing but dependent on which encoder is turned, some variables in the code will have to change.

Do I have to write a separate function for each one of them? It is not possible to pass an argument (the interrupt pins number in this case) to the called function from the attachInterrupt and I don't really see any other viable option than to write 5 functions (rotary1() rotary2()...) containing the exact same code with a few variables changed.

One other option I thought of would be to call an "intermediary" function which checks for the currently relevant pin and then calls the rotary function with this information passed down, but this is far from an elegant solution and probably slows down the whole process a lot. I really don't want to have to do a separate check for which encoder is being turned because this information is already there, I just don't know how to access it.

I would appreciate if someone with more experience could point me in the right direction here, as it seems very wrong to me even as a relative beginner to write the same code so many times.

Comment: No, you don't need separate interrupt service routines (ISR).  The hardware is designed to jump to a location that is set in a register.  The hardware device has no idea if the addresses are the same or different.  However, different functions are used to make interrupt determination easier.

Comment: Some interrupt controllers only provide one address register.  When the interrupt occurs, the ISR is in charge of determining the source of the interrupt by reading registers in the Interrupt Controller to determine what triggered the interrupt.  Different interrupt controllers behave differently; no standard.

Comment: Since you tagged C++, you could create a rotary parent class (that has most of the functionality).  Declare child classes or instances for each rotary.

Comment: first of all thanks for answering, the problem is in the arduino language I can attach an interrupt to a pin and call a function but cannot pass it any arguments. So I would set up 5 such interrupts, attached to 5 individual pins and call five functions which essentially all do the same. I don't really see how creating rotary objects would help me here, or is it possible to call an object's function maybe? so rotary1.interrupt()  or something like that? And then have that function get its parameters from the object's properties? Wait that could work :D

Comment: Learn interrupt programming in C on the bare part -- from the Atmel application notes -- and you'll see it's not possible for certain pins.  Many pins share the same interrupt.  And some don't. It's up to you to determine which one fired.  The "arduino language" is a layer of abstraction over what's going on.  It is slow, bloated, and cloaks true understanding of how to program the device.

Comment: what specific chip are you using?

Comment: create one line interrupt functions, which all call the same function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found, you need as many ISRs as there are pins. But you don't need to duplicate the code in them.

*Note: Depending on your algorithm, you might need more than one handling function, for example if you use both inputs of a encoder to interrupt.*

**The C way**

Write a single separated function that takes as many parameters as you see fit.

Call this function from your ISRs with the appropriate parameters.

```
void handleInterrupt(int which) {
    // do whatever you like to do with "which"
}

void interruptServiceRoutine1() {
    handleInterrupt(1);
}

void interruptServiceRoutine2() {
    handleInterrupt(2);
}

void interruptServiceRoutine3() {
    handleInterrupt(3);
}
```

**The C++ way**

Write a class to represent a rotary encoder. Include a method that handles the interrupt.

Call this method with the respective rotary encoder object from your ISRs.

```
class RotaryEncoder {
public:
    void handleInterrupt();
};

void RotaryEncoder::handleInterrupt() {
    // do whatever you like to do
}

RotaryEncoder rotaryEncoder1;
RotaryEncoder rotaryEncoder2;
RotaryEncoder rotaryEncoder3;

void interruptServiceRoutine1() {
    rotaryEncoder1.handleInterrupt();
}

void interruptServiceRoutine2() {
    rotaryEncoder2.handleInterrupt();
}

void interruptServiceRoutine3() {
    rotaryEncoder3.handleInterrupt();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, those two ways are what I thought of as well, just thought maybe there's an easier solution I'm not seeing. One more question - what's the difference in the c++ way and the c way, why is one more suited to that language?

Comment: Well, C++ is the language used by Arduino, but if you don't program object-oriented, you would like to follow the more functional/imperative way of C. Choose what fits best to your thinking. You can use either way in both languages, but certain combinations are easier. ;-)

Comment: *"maybe there's an easier solution I'm not seeing"* an even easier way? One line per interrupt, and a single handler? Did you search for a library for rotary encoders someone else might have already written for Arduino?

Comment: Ok so it's just about OOP or not. I guess I thought there would be some specific syntax to interrupts, like you could pass an argument but have to do it in a specific way, or that you could get the interrupt-number in the called function in some way... Either way, thank you very much, I think I know what I'm doing now :D

Comment: In most cases ISRs should run as fast as possible. And if the hardware (or some "invisible" software) will save some register's contents before writing an interrupt index in it (or to some memory location), it simply needs some time. -- Actually most µC use different addresses for their ISRs, be it as start address or as vector. This is dispatching in hardware. Other µC makes you scan through interrupt flags. And there are more ways, HW designers are so creative. (No offend! :-D) Arduino's library hides this below their API in the chosen way.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if ISRs were provided with the index of the interrupt that called them. Then we could handle them in a more generic manner and avoid a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: In 40+ years of programming embedded software I never felt the need to have the interrupt number as an argument in an interrupt handler. Instead, I was glad to have a separated interrupt handler per interrupt source. If was rather a PITA to have to `switch` (of chain `if` - `else if`) on primitive hardware like the PIC, where you need to check multiple interrupt flags to decide which interrupt triggered the interrupt handler. Just let the hardware do the job. I think a generic interrupt handler is commonly an architectural error.

Comment: The design you're inferring is not what I'm talking about. To call a C function to handle an interrupt, you need the proper prologue/epilogue. A single wrapper ISR can do the prologue/epilogue and dispatch to the C function via a function pointer. Knowing the interrupt # would make this work with a single ISR (though of course, separate C functions to handle each interrupt). Otherwise you have to use code generation to create a separate ISR wrapper for every C function.

Comment: Yes, sure. And what is your problem with that? Each compiler I used produces these prologues and epilogues automatically, there is no need for manual work. Your version needs more CPU cycles than the version with separate ISRs. So, where is the advantage? -- Since this gets off-topic and is seemingly opinionated, I'd like to stop the discussion here. StackOverflow is the wrong place to discuss such architectural issues. Feel free to start a thread somewhere more appropriate and link to it.